# Firebase serialize class with UUID member

Tags: java, firebase, deserialization, uuid, azure-cognitive-services

I am getting this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.UUID is missing a constructor with no arguments
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp$zza.zzcg(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zze(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp$zza.zzcg(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zze(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp$zza.zzcg(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zze(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.example.brewc.react.main.Fragments.ContactsPageFragment$2.onDataChange(ContactsPageFragment.java:109)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakg.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalg.zzcxk(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalj$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Here is the line of error:

```
User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

**User.java**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Base64;

import com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.contract.Face;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class User {
    private String email, userID, displayName, phoneNumber, profilePicture, bio;
    private Face details;
    private ArrayList<Face> database;
    private ArrayList<String> contacts;

    public User() {}

    public User(String email,
                String userID,
                String displayName,
                Face details,
                String phoneNumber,
                String profliePicture) {
        this.email = email.trim();
        this.userID = userID;
        this.displayName = displayName.trim();
        this.details = details;
        this.database = new ArrayList<Face>();
        this.contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber.trim().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        this.profilePicture = profliePicture;
        this.bio = "";
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return this.userID;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.displayName;
    }

    public Face getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }

    public ArrayList<Face> getDatabase() {
        return this.database;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getContacts() {
        return this.contacts;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getProfilePicture() {
        return this.profilePicture;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return this.bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String message) {
        this.bio = message;
    }

    public void addContact() {
        this.contacts.add("DvMzHKD0fdbjAVUCw9a5XJZEeYb2");
    }
}
```

Here is Microsoft's Face class structure:

```
public class Face {
    public UUID faceId;
    public FaceRectangle faceRectangle;
    public FaceLandmarks faceLandmarks;
    public FaceAttribute faceAttributes;

    public Face() {
    }
}
```

I understand that firebase needs an empty constructor, so how can I fix this?

Comment: Im pretty sure uid is just a string if you're talking about user id's on firebase. If not psot the code for uuid too

Comment: @brianxautumn [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) is a native Java class.

Comment: Post the entire stack trace in your question.

Comment: You might have to manually parse the data snapshot yourself

Comment: @brianxautumn yeah it's starting to look like it.